# Why doesn't the cursor update in this JS code?

Tags: javascript, css

I am writing javascript code and I have come to the conclusion that changing the cursor on any/all element(s) of the html page is not affected immediately when executed before CPU-intensive code. Even when moving my mouse around, nothing changes while the code is running.

For example, this code only makes the cursor change AFTER the for loop is done:

```
$('*').css('cursor', 'wait'); for (let i=0; i<10000000000; i++) ;
```

And if I run the following, the user won't even see any change at all during the loop:

```
$('*').css('cursor', 'wait'); for (let i=0; i<10000000000; i++) ; $('*').css('cursor', '');
```

Any other css change (background color, element sizes, etc) works perfectly, but not the cursor...

Anyway to get around this problem ?

(Was tested on Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: Maybe wrap the for loop in `setTimeout(function(){},1000)`?

Comment: `$('*').css('background-color', 'black'); for (let i=0; i<10000000000; i++) ; $('*').css('background-color', 'blue');` also behaves the same.

Comment: pineapplerind, I already tried that..

Answer (score -1):

can us:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            html {
                height: 100%;
            }

            body {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            document.body.style.cursor = 'wait'
            getData()

            function getData() {
                for (let index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
                    console.log(index)
                }
                endWork()
            }
            function endWork() {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    document.body.style.cursor = 'default'
                    alert('change cursor to default')
                }, 3000);
            }
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: but my running code is not always going to be done in 2 seconds ;)
Where do you put my for loop in your example ?

Comment: if you put the for-loop that I posted, it doesn't work.